# iPhone Web Application JavaScript events break after waking up from sleep

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, wakeup

I'm trying to build a mobile-safari/iphone web-app using jQuery code I already wrote for the desktop version of the app.  The problem I'm having is that when my phone goes to sleep with the web-app running, when I wake it up (slide to unluck) the JavaScript event handlers no longer function.  In this case meaning when I click on a link that used to perform an AJAX update via an onclick event it actually follows the link by opening the page in a new Safari window, breaking the appearance of the native iPhone app.

The code that stops working:

```
$(function() {
var ajaxLoad;
var ajaxClick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("body").load( $(this).attr("href"), ajaxLoad );
}
ajaxLoad = function() {
    $(this).find("a").click( ajaxClick );
}
$("a").bind( "click", ajaxClick );
});
```

When the code works the result of the link will open in the web-app frame, when it breaks, the code will open in a new safari window, breaking the look of an actual app.

Comment: if you will post some of the code - it might help...

Comment: As requested, I added the jQuery code to the question.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  I'm experiencing a similar problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204438/iphone-jquery-breaks-after-triggering-the-email-overlay

Answer (score 0):

Not tested - but would it help to add 'return false' to the end of the ajaxClick function so that the link does not activate.